# Regex with \+?= is not working / escaping '+' as expected

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code:

```
import re
pattern = r'.className\s*\+?=\s*.*?\+?[\'"](.*?)["\']'
code_str = "if (El.className == 'blue' ) {\nEl.className = 'className20';\n}\n"
re.findall(pattern, code_str)
```

*Output >>>* `['blue', 'className20']`

I am only wanting the output `['className20']`.

[*Update*] 
It also needs to handle this concatenation case where `some_str` is combined with `className20`. It should still only return `['className20']`.

```
code_str2 = "if (El.className == 'blue' ) {\nEl.className = some_str + 'className20';\n}\n"
re.findall(pattern, code_str)
```

I've also tried.

```
pattern = r'.className\s*\+{,1}={1}\s*.*?\+?[\'"](.*?)["\']'
pattern = r'.className\s*\+?[=]{1}\s*.*?\+?[\'"](.*?)["\']'
```

Any insight is welcomed. The problem seems to be that `==` appears in `code_str`. The pattern I'm using is too greedy. My understanding is that `\+` is properly escaping the `+` sign, but I could be wrong.

Comment: what is the logic behind the acceptable pattern? Is it camel case followed by digits ?

Comment: If you want **word** after = but not **word** after == use a two step process : find word after == , and delete it , including the == . Second step ( using a different regexp, find **word ** after =

Answer (score 1):

Why is there a `.*?` after `=\s*`? You want to allow anything to follow an equals followed by any amount of space? That's what allows `== 'blue'` to be accepted; the `\s*` does nothing, but the following `.*?` is matching the `=` following the first `=`. Drop it, and it works:

```
import re
pattern = r'.className\s*\+?=\s*\+?[\'"](.*?)["\']'
code_str = "if (El.className == 'blue' ) {\nEl.className = 'className20';\n}\n"
re.findall(pattern, code_str)
```

producing `['className20']` as expected. The question is whether there was some reason to allow arbitrary characters there.

Comment: This does work as you described, but I've realized in testing it that I have a concatenation case that needs to be handled.  I've updated my question with this 2nd case.